# Move the cursor in a textbox in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to use VBA to paste a chart from Excel to a text box (in line with text) in Word.

I find that when I paste just after selecting the text box, the chart will be pasted above the text box instead of in the text box. To paste it in the text box I have to move the cursor in the box first.

Knowing that, I read that `SetFocus` can move the cursor in the text box; however I got an error message "Method or data member not found" at the line of `SetFocus`.

Could any one help me to move the cursor in the text box?

Below is what I used for copying and pasting:

```
xlsfile.ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy    'Copying has no problem
ActiveDocument.Shapes(boxName).SetFocus      'I cannot find the function in the suggested function list
Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteBitmap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, these two lines did the job! Thanks everybody!

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(boxName).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
```

Answer (score 1):

**Logic I used**:

1. Export Chart to user's temp directory as image
2. Insert the image in the textbox using `Shp.Fill`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Excel Objects/Variables
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim imgFileName As String

    '~~> Word Objects/Variables
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim FlName As String

    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet and graph
    Set objChrt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
    Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

    imgFileName = TempPath & "myChart.png"

    '~~> Export Graph as image
    myChart.Export Filename:=imgFileName, Filtername:="PNG"

    '~~> This is your word document which has the textbox
    FlName = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\DeleteMeLater.Docx"

    '~~> Create Word application object
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open your word file
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    '~~> Insert Image in the textbox
    oWordDoc.Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture (imgFileName)

    '~~> Kill the temp file
    Kill imgFileName
End Sub

'~~> Function to get user's temp directory
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**NOTE**:

In the above code, I have shown how to do this from MS-Excel. With minor edits, you can do it from MS-Word as well.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, I tried using Export and Fill but there are a lot of problems and errors for opening, exporting and filling which takes a long time to sort out (The code collects one chart from many charts in a worksheet from many worksheets from different files and folders). Again thank you very much for helping. It would be nice if anybody knows how to move the cursor in a text box, so that I can proceed with copying and pasting.

Comment: Hello, I just found I should use Activate to move the cursor. However, an error saying the method is not available on that object occurred at "ActiveDocument.Shapes(boxName).Activate" Does anyone know why?

Comment: There is no need to activate. Can you share your complete code in your question?